# How to display open graph objects in gallery view in news feed?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, feed

I am using Facebook Open Graph with an approved action called "order". When our users make a purchase on the site, we will post what they bought in timeline and news feed. I chose the gallery view in aggregation. It shows up correctly in timeline, but not in news feed. In the newsfeed, the products are in a list view. My guess is that I'm passing the urls of the product page back to facebook, so it shows as a list of items, not just the pictures. What's the right way to make the products show up in news feed as a gallery, like pinterest or instagram?

Here's my code to post the products

```
purchase.products.each do |product|
  graph_api.put_connections("me", "#{namespace}:order?product=#{product_url(product)}")
end
```

Thanks